# C# cannot add the same XmlAttribute in 2 Xmlnodes

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

I have created XmlAttribute, and added it to XmlNode, everything works fine.
When trying to add the same XmlAttribute to another XmlNode, it **steals** the attribute from the first XmlNode i added it to.

My Scenario is like this:
Father node has ability, if this ability available, then i have create a new node and set it as child node for this father node.
Father node has 3 (X-Y-Z) attributes, If father node has ability then i create child node, and add these attributes to it also.
My problem is when i do:

```
fatherNode.Attributes.Append(attribute1);
```

The attribute is added to collection, But when i do this afterwards:

```
childNode.Attributes.Append(attribute1);
```

It removes the attribute from fatherNode and now it is ONLY in childNode.

What is this behavior ? is there a way to avoid it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
fatherNode.Attributes.Append(attribute1);
childNode.Attributes.Append( (XmlAttribute)attribute1.Clone());
```

Comment: Work-around works, Dunno why XmlDocument works like this by design.

Comment: XmlAttribute has property ParentNode and if you Append it to second node, it's parentNode is set to this new one and lost reference to old one

Comment: yes i saw it, but i set reference to XmlAttribute in my Attributes collection of fatherNode, so how come this reference is changed ? I understand changing ParentNode of attribute, but why also updating the Attributes of father, they could keep it. this way the parentNode should be known as LatestParentNode :)